# How can I re-draw surfaceview?

Tags: video, surfaceview, mediarecorder, recording

i'm struggle to recording video on android studio. 
for below source code. I can record it for once but not twice by pressing button and pressing more time to stop it.

I want to record more video. so I click it again thinking video record again. 
but app terminated not showing any error on android studio.

I think I should redraw surfaceview to not to have any problem. 
any idea to recording more than 1 times?

```
package ica.com.myvideo;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.media.CamcorderProfile;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
    Button myButton;
    MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    boolean is_recording;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        checkPermission();

        is_recording=false;

        mediaRecorder=new MediaRecorder();
        initMediaRecorder();

        SurfaceView myVideoView=(SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        surfaceHolder=myVideoView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        myButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(is_recording){
                    mediaRecorder.stop();
                    mediaRecorder.release();
                }else{
                    mediaRecorder.start();
                    is_recording=true;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void initMediaRecorder() {
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
        CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile_HQ=CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P);
        mediaRecorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile_HQ);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath()+"/testv.mp4");
        Log.e("error",Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath()+"/testv.mp4");
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.e("error","surface created");
        prepareMediaRecorder();
    }

    private void prepareMediaRecorder() {
        Log.e("error","prepareMediaRecorder");
        mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }

    private void checkPermission(){
        String[] permssions={
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        };

        int permissionCheck= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        for(int i=0; i<permssions.length; i++) {

            permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permssions[i]);
            if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if(permissionCheck==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        }else{
            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,permssions[0])){
            }else{
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,permssions,1);
            }


        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(requestCode==1){
            for(int i=0; i<permissions.length; i++){
                if(grantResults[i]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    //
                }else{
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```